# Search the index of different characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am trying to get the index of the first instance of a character given a list of characters

I tried this:

```py
first_char = line.index('&')                   
second_char = line.find(" ",first_char) or line.find("(",first_char) or line.find(";",first_char)
print(line[first_char:second_char])
```

It's not working for some instances as I can get more then one character per line.
I know that I can built something using IF and Elses but it just seem a bit complicated for something quite simple I imagine.

Examples:

```
Text --> " left join &lib_prefix.abcd( "

Result "&lib_prefix.abcd"

Text --> " left join &lib_prefix.abcd "

Result "&lib_prefix.abcd"

Text --> " left join &lib_prefix.abcd; "

Result "&lib_prefix.abcd"

Text --> " left join &lib_prefix.abcd;( "

Result "&lib_prefix.abcd"
```

Comment: It would help if you edited the question and added an example of the text you're starting with and what you want  in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably the wrong approach. `index()` either finds the index or throws `ValueError: substring not found`. `find()`, on the other hand, either finds the index or returns `-1`. So neither will work in a pattern like:

```
second_char = line.find(" ",first_char) or line.find("(",first_char) or line.find(";",first_char)
```

…except in the case where it finds the first thing — a space in the case. If it doesn't find that, it return `-1`  (or throws and error if you use `find()`.

To extract that substring you probably better off with a regular expression. Something like:

```
import re

line = " left join &lib_prefix.abcd;("
found = re.search(r'\&.*?(?=[\s(;])', line)
if found:
    print(found[0])
else:
    print("not found")
# prints &lib_prefix.abcd
```

The regex basically says:

- Find and ampersand `\&` (needs to be escaped with `\` because `&` means something to regex).
- Followed by any characters `.*?` that
  follows something in your set of characters `(?=[\s(;])` (`\s` is for whitespace character)